# How render PDF from a HTTP POST using Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this strange architecture that uses Rails as a middleware, so in a Java web service a PDF is generated passing a Post Payload to it using Rails, and then I do not know how to render it. I had tried to use WickedPdf, but I do not need to generate a PDF just respond with a raw data. Using render body or render plain, get's an EventMachine string as an answer like *so* *EventMachine::HttpClient:0x007faa21293510'*

Answer (score 0):

If you already have your file, you can use `send_file` to responde with your pdf:

```
send_file your_file_url, :type => "application/pdf", filename: "your file name"
```

This should work for you. Good luck!

Comment: Rails consume a web service via `EventMachine::HttpRequest`, so in the controller, I just have after the request the server response.
Also, I tried with send_data and this is how my I ended receiving the EventMachine Hash.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry about the content of my question, I realize the problem was in the HttpRequest, not in the rendering which by the way must be done using SEND_DATA.
I Hope this can help someone in the future.